# Why CURL not working into production server?

Tags: cloudflare

today I am trying to download an webpage url using curl. And here I see a peculiar problem.

When I run my code from local machine, its collect everything well. But when I run my code from my production server, its get 503 error.

I see that site use cloudflare service. But my question is

**If they protect scrap from production, why can't protect when I trying from locally?**

Can anyone help me please?
my code is :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
      <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     </head>
    <body>
      <?php
      include('simple_html_dom.php');
      $new_url = 'https://www.bagdoom.com/electronics/computers/webcams.html';

      $header = array();
      $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
      $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
      $header[] =  "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
      $header[] =  "Connection: keep-alive";
      $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
      $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
      $header[] = "Pragma: ";

      $curl = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $new_url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $new_url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
      $str = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);

      $html_list = new simple_html_dom();
      $new_html_list = $html_list->load($str);
      
      foreach($new_html_list->find("#awac_catalog_container li.item h2.product-name a") as $e){
        echo $e->href . '<br>';
      }

      ?>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: I need help. Anyone help please.

Answer (score 0):

One of the services Cloudflare offers is [IP Reputation checks](https://www.cloudflare.com/security/); in short if a site has been seen to be abusive across the Cloudflare network - it can be challenged with a captcha or JavaScript challenge page.

It is likely that the IP Address reputation of your server on production is quite low (especially if the IP Address has been recycled by a cloud server provider). The IP reputation of your local server, may however, be considerably more trustworthy.

In order to bypass this, you will need to get the site to [whitelist your servers IP Address](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217074967-How-do-I-control-access-to-my-site-) in the Firewall app in the Cloudflare dashboard.

Comment: thanx mjsa. I don't know why, this url scraping now working well. but I will try your step if I get error again. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @mjsa, have you any idea for - (1) above scripts work sometime but don't work sometime. sometime it scrap data but sometime it can't scrap html. why?